# C++ values of global float pointers changes from function

Tags: c++, pointers, global-variables, declaration

I declared a global float 2d pointer. Allocates memory in separate function and initialize in another fuction.But when values, it differs from function to function.

```
float **x; // Global 
int i,j;  // Global

void init(){
    x = new float *[2];
    for(i=0;i<2;i++)
        x [i] = new float [60];
}

void calc(){
    for(i=0;i<2;i++)  
        for(j=0;j<60;j++)
        x[i][j]= // Some calculation

    for(i=0;i<2;i++){
        for(j=0;j<60;j++) 
            cout<<x[i][j]<<" "; // Here it prints a value1
        cout<<"\n";
    }
}

void main(){
    init();
    calc();
    for(i=0;i<2;i++){
        for(j=0;j<60;j++) 
            cout<<x[i][j]<<" "; // Here it entirely different value (1st 2 different values and rest as 0)
}
```

I have to use 2d float pointer in all functions with user defined size. Any better way other than global declaration ??

Comment: Any compelling reason you can't use `std::vector`? Also you are accessing the outer array out of bounds in every single piece of the code. That outer array contains 2 elements but each loop iterates over 3 elements total.

Comment: You are accessing the outer array out of bounds in `init()`.

Comment: sorry it was typing mistake and now corrected.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should be using std::vector<float> instead of a float pointer with "naked new".  There is no reason to be declaring i and j as globals as they are only used as loop variables over the float values.

Secondly, the answer to your question: "is there a better way than global variables?"

1. For this simple code, simply pass them as arguments to the functions and declare them in main.
2. If this is not a representative example, then you should consider using a structure or array to represent the data *and* the methods that operate on it.  That is, after all, the whole point of object-oriented programming: to bring the data and the functions that operate on that data into the same place.